# how to excute js in "view-source:url" in chrome extension content_script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Now I am writing a chrome extension, I want to run javascript of content_script (chrome extension) in source-code page,

but It seems js don't run in "view-source" page
for example :`view-source:http://www.google.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it, it is blocked for security reasons.

If you are trying to provide a tool that helps developers look at the Developer Tools API's that you have access to. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html